# Add attribute to wildcard Requestmapping path?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is there a way to add an attribute to all paths of a certain user?
I.e I am trying to reach the current logged in administrator on all pages the administrator can reach, but I don't want to add this attribute to every single controller.

Something like this, where I don't need to return anything:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"admin/**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void adminPaths(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Security? What view layer are you using? Better solution might be to use Spring Security taglibs to get access to logged user properties. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26208602/1291150

Comment: Yes I do, I will try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ModelAttribute`s on a method in a controller. An `@ModelAttribute` on a method indicates the purpose of that method is to add one or more model attributes to all controller methods:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {
...

    @ModelAttribute
    public void populateModel(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        // add more ...
    }

...
}
```

`@ModelAttribute` methods in a controller are invoked before `@RequestMapping` methods, within the same controller.

For truly wildcard matching, you can use `ControllerAdvice` and `ModelAttribute`s on methods together. Something like following:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class AdminPopulatorAdvice {
        @ModelAttribute
        public void populateModel(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
            // examine the request
            // if its path contains /admin, then add attribute
            model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
            // add more ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I was using Spring security.

Bohuslav pointed me into the right direction and ended up here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html